# HTML form input to gravity forms on other page

Tags: html, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I'm a designer with a bit of developing skills but got stuck on this one:

On a Wordpress website (for a Bed and Breakfast) i'm currently building i got a HTML form on the homepage. On that form you can choose the date you want to check-in check-out etc. I want to link that form to an advanced booking page with a gravity form. In that Gravity form the fields for check-in, check-out etc needs to be prefilled with the input from the homepage.

Does anyone know how to do this? and maybe got an example for me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried to use the populate dynamically function. But i got stuck when i want the input from "Field A" on the homepage to "dynamic field A"

Comment: If you can provide some of your code with specific questions then you will find people will be able to help easier